# What does object's __init__() method do in python?

Tags: python, object, init

While reading the code of OpenStack and I encountered this.

A class named 'Service' inherits the base class 'object', and then in Service's `__init__()` method, object's `__init__` is called. The related code looks like this:

the class definition:

```
class Service(object):
```

and Service's init method definition:

```
def __init__(self, host, binary, topic, manager, report_interval=None,
             periodic_interval=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

and a call to super(the 'object' here) in Service's init:

```
super(Service, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't understand last call, `object.__init__()` what does it actually do?
can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is that object.__init__() method does nothing except check that no arguments have been passed in.  See [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l2847) for details.

When called on an instance of *Service*, the *[super()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super)* call will delegate to object.__init__() and nothing will happen.

However, when called on an instance of a subclass of *Service*, things get more interesting.  The *super()* call can potentially delegate to some class other than *object*, a class that is a parent of the instance but not a parent of *Service*.  For details on how this works and why it is useful, see the blog post [Python's Super Considered Super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)!

The following example (somewhat contrived) shows how a subclass of *Service* can cause the *super* call in *Service* to be directed to another class called *Color*:

```
class Service(object):
    def __init__(self, host, binary, topic, manager, report_interval=None,
             periodic_interval=None, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Initializing Service'
        super(Service, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, color='red', **kwargs):
        print 'Initializing Color'
        self.color = color
        super(Color, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class ColoredService(Service, Color):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        print 'Initializing Colored Service'
        super(ColoredService, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)

c = ColoredService('host', 'bin', 'top', 'mgr', 'ivl', color='blue')
```

In the example, initializations occur in the following order:

1. Initializing Colored Service
2. Initializing Service
3. Initializing Color
4. Initialize object -- doing nothing except argument checking

Comment: the reference [Python's Super Considered Super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The `ColoredService` constructor allows e.g. `foo='bar'` to be passed, but this will ultimately fail with `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`. So what's the point in passing `*args` and `**kwargs` in the `super` calls for the `Service` and `Color` classes? Your example will work just the same without them (and will be more robust).

Comment: @ekhumoro That comment should be directed at the writers of OpenStack.  The ``*args`` part was from their code and callers have to respect that signature.  I just added *Color* and *ColoredService* to show how the MRO could chain from *Service* to *Color* to *object*.

Answer (score 3):

`super()` **does not always return a proxy for the parent class.** Instead, it returns a proxy for *the next class in [MRO](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/)*. In single-inheritance there is no difference between MRO and the inheritance chain. In multiple-inheritance, MRO may result in a class on the *other* inheritance chain instead.

Comment: but there's no multiple-inheritance here, as Service inherits directly from object

Comment: @can.: But what inherits from `Service`?

Comment: I've read the article about MRO, and I think because Service inherits directly from object, the super() has no ambiguity here. Whaterver inherits from Service does not make a difference.

Comment: @can.: Go to the example in the section titled "The C3 Method Resolution Order" and look at `B`'s MRO.

Answer (score 1):

`object.__init__()` doesn't actually do anything but the `super()` call should be included even when a class only has `object` as a superclass.

> One big problem with 'super' is that it sounds like it will cause the
>   superclass's copy of the method to be called. This is simply not the
>   case, it causes the next method in the MRO to be called (...) People
>   omit calls to super(...).**init** if the only superclass is 'object',
>   as, after all, object.**init** doesn't do anything! However, this is
>   very incorrect. Doing so will cause other classes' **init** methods to
>   not be called.

http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

Comment: But note that the OP's example code will fail if anything is passed via `*args` and `**kwargs` (unless it's run with python 2.5 or earlier).

Comment: can you two explain your ideas with more details? @ekhumoro