# Python: An object constructor calls itself

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have encountered the following code. An object constructor calls itself:

```
  class StatusMixin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StatusMixin, self).__init__()

        self.does_something()
```

Is there any practical reason why it is implemented like this? I think people use  the`super` method only in the context of multiple inheritance.

Comment: `StatusMixin.__init__` does not call itself; it calls `X.__init__`, where `X` is the next class in its method resolution order. (Commenting here because the question itself contains a false assumption; Daniel Roseman's answer covers this.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does object's \_\_init\_\_() do in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611712/what-does-objects-init-do-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention multiple inheritance. This class is described as a mixin: that is, it's specifically *intended* to be used in the case of multiple inheritance. It will be one of the elements in a class hierarchy, but not the top or the bottom. That's why it calls `super` - the next item in the method resolution order will not in practice be `object`, but some other class.

Consider this hierarchy:

```
class Super(object):
    pass

class Sub(StatusMixin, Super)
    pass
```

and examine `Sub.mro()`:

```
[__main__.Sub, __main__.StatusMixin, __main__.Super, object]
```

So you see that here the result of the super call in `StatusMixin` is not `object` at all, but `Super`.

Comment: +1 - This is the main reason it's necessary, i.e. when you don't know what the superclass type will be. However, there are a few potential issues when using `super` to call a superclass constructor with parameters - see [this](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).