# what does super really do in python

Tags: python, object, initialization

I have just read [Method Resolution Order](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) by GvR, but I wonder if the following statement holds true(I agree with this) in [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). So `super()` causes the next method in the MRO to be called? Also noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8611748/325224).

> One big problem with 'super' is that it sounds like it will cause the
>   superclass's copy of the method to be called. This is simply not the
>   case, it causes the next method in the MRO to be called (...)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'init A'

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init B'

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print 'init C'

c = C()
```

gives

```
init A
init C
```

While

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'init A'

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'init B'

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print 'init C'

c = C()
```

gives

```
init B
init A
init C
```

Comment: So ... What's your question?

Comment: super() causes the next method in the MRO to be called?

Comment: Yes it does. Did you examine example in the article you linked, that is https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/example1-1.py?

Comment: The mro in example1-2 is [E, C, A, D, B, object]. Both E and C's init method has one arg, but A's has no arg, so throw exception at A's init method(`__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the expected results in both cases... In the first case C calls to A (next class in MRO) which prints "init A" and returns so flow comes back to C which prints "init C" and returns. Matches your output.

In the second case C calls A (next in MRO) which calls B (next to A in MRO) which prints "init B" and returns so flow comes back to A which prints "init A" and returns back to C which prints "init C".

Comment: yes, the `super` is so tricky as demonstrated in [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: @schemacs: `super` is not tricky - it calls the next method in the mro, period. Multiple inheritance is tricky but that's another topic.