# object.__new__ takes no parameters

Tags: python

I keep getting the following error on a piece of python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):     
File"..."...in <module>   
app = App(root)  
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Here is the code it is referring to:

```
from tkinter import *
from ScaleAndOffsetConverter import *

class App():
    def __init_(self, master):

        self.c_var = DoubleVar()
        self.t_conv.ScaleAndOffsetConverter("F", "C", 1.8, 32)
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        L1 = Label(frame, textvariable = self.result_var)
        L2 = Label(frame, text = "Deg C")
        E = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.c_var)
        L3 = Label( frame, text = "Deg F")
        B = Button(frame, text = "convert", command = self.convert)
        L1.grid(row=1,column=1)
        L2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        E.grid(row=0, column=1)
        L3.grid(row=0,column=0)
        B.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
        self.result_var = DoubleVar

     def convert(self):
           c = self.c_var.get()
           self.result_var.set(self.t_conv.convert(c))

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.wm_title("Temp Converter")
root.mainloop()
```

I know that similar questions have been posted to this one but i still don't fully understand how to fix this problem - does anybody know why it is appearing or how to fix it?

Comment: `self.t_conv.ScaleAndOffsetConverter` is also going to fail

Comment: Raspberry Pi and its Debian derivative are irrelevant to this question. I assume you added them because you're running the code there, but unless it's actually related to the OS, please don't add those tags. Additionally, I **hope** the indentation of `def convert(self)` is just a formatting mistake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `__init__()` function is misspelled!

Replace

`def __init_(self, master):` with

`def __init__(self, master):`

Make sure there are double underbars before and after the word init.  These functions are known as "dunder" methods and as you can see the number of underbars does matter!

Python looks for your implementation of `__init__` and cannot find it, so it uses `Object`'s `__init__`, which does nothing but check that no arguments have been passed to it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611712/what-does-objects-init-do-in-python) post.  This check results in the `TypeError` you are seeing.